# I ran out of available quote symbols in javascript!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't believe it, but this is really happening. I ran out of available quote symbols using jquery and javascript native functions together. Can somebody help? Maybe there is yet another symbol?

```
var t=setTimeout('$("#popupChange").html('<img src="http://servername/pdf/picture/genericThrobber.gif" />');',2000);
```

**EDIT**: Firebug messages about "missing ) after argument list" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escaping them using `\'` should work.

```
var t=setTimeout('$("#popupChange")
.html(\'<img src="http://servername/pdf/picture/genericThrobber.gif" />\');',
2000);
```

(added line breaks to get rid of the scroll bar)

you could also pass an anonymous function instead of a string:

```
var t=setTimeout(function() { $("#popupChange")
.html('<img src="http://servername/pdf/picture/genericThrobber.gif" />');},
2000);
```

should be fine either way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the characters using a backslash.

On the inner `'`, make it `\'`